# Вычисление энтропии большого файла

Tags: c, windows

Набросал функцию вычисления энтропии файла:

```
double ComputeEntropy(PUCHAR buf, size_t bufsize)
{
  int* rng = (int*)_alloca(256 * sizeof(*rng));
  memset(rng, 0, 256 * sizeof(*rng));
  double ent = 0.0, src = bufsize;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < bufsize; i++) rng[buf[i]]++;
  for (int    i = 0; i < 256;     i++)
  {
    if (rng[i] > 0) ent += rng[i] * log2(rng[i] / src);
  }

  return -ent / src;
}
```

Компилятор MS ругается предупреждениями использования `_alloca`. Собственно, есть ли какие альтернативы этому методу? Да и вообще, насколько будет надежен с точки зрения безопасности данный код?

Comment: а почему не malloc обычный?

Comment: ещё вариант `new int[size]`

Comment: @nick_n_a, тут же C.

Answer (score 1):

Вам вообще не нужно динамическое  выделение памяти. Можно создать обычный массив, вы же заранее знаете его размер:

```
int rng[256] = {0};
```

---

А вообще функция [`_alloca`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/alloca?view=vs-2019) объявлена устаревшей (deprecated). Более безопасная версия — [`_malloca`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/malloca?view=vs-2019).

Кстати, интересно, почему счетчик `i` в первом цикле у вас имеет тип `size_t`, а во втором — `int`? Думаю, будет лучше и во втором цикле использовать `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Вот , используется второй стек. *(запасной, в реальности юзаю для исключений)*

```
#include <stdlib.h>
unsigned int const stacksize = 8000000;
unsigned int stackpointer ; // индекс от физического адреса
void * stackphisicalpointer ;

void * malloca(unsigned int s){
  stackpointer -= s ;
  return ((char*)stackphisicalpointer) + stackpointer ; }

void f(void){
    unsigned int    oldstackpointer = stackpointer ;
    int * rng = ( int * ) malloca ( 256U * sizeof(int) ) ;
    ( * rng ) = 1 ;
    stackpointer = oldstackpointer ; }

int main() {
  stackphisicalpointer  = malloc ( stacksize ) ;
  stackpointer = stacksize ;
  f();
  free(stackphisicalpointer); }
```